# How get user info from google via API?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I'm developing API to integrate rails app with google.

I receive from client only:

```
{
  provider:     'google_oauth2',
  user_id:      'USER_ID',
  access_token: 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
}
```

But I need create user and save it into database if user is not registered etc. I have models `user` and `authentication` (user has many authentications):

```
class User
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, 
            presense: true 

  has_many :providers
endd

class Authentication
  validates :provider, :user_id, :access_token, :refresh_token, :expires_at, 
            presense: true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Google app is already created and all permissions are set up correctly.

Problem:

To save user with authentication into DB - I need to have all fields.

Question:

If I have `provider`, `user_id` and `access_token`, 
  how can I get additional fields: 
  `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `refresh_token` and `expires_at`.

Which API request should I make?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get

Comment: @DaImTo, thanks but is this information can be received without authentication and google app access?

Comment: no the user has to be authenticated and have a Google+ account to my knowledge this is the only way to get the user information from Google.